# Edit Outlook .msg file - how to save it from Outlook Draft to desire location using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, editing, office-automation, msg

Given: Using Powershell Copy folder with template file to different directory
Re-name the .msg file and edit .msg file for recurring common values and Save.

Problem: The outlook open the file and save it in the Outlook draft folder rather than editing and saving it to given copied directory.

On google search, I found the Word document editing programming but not for Outlook. In word document programming we could search specific word and replace it in the document.

I am not sure if similar could be achieved with Outlook or not.

Following is what I successful to achieve

1. Copy rename of msg file into new folder at different location.
2. Edit the desire body message values
3. Creating a draft file within Outlook

Following is what I failed to achieve and need assistance with.

1. Change of Subject Line
2. Saving of Document outside of Outlook

Following is what I would expected to achieve

1. Changing the subject line and replacing common values using find and replace feature outside of Outlook program using Powershell.

Requesting assistance.

Thank you all for those who give this their thoughts and efforts in advance.

The code is as follows

```
$LBStempfolder = Template folder location
$newfolder = new directory location

If(test-path $LBStempfolder)
{ if(!(test-path $newfolder))
{ $newfolder = New-Item -ItemType "Directory" -Path "LBStempfolder" -Name "XYZ" -Confirm
Write-host $newfolder
if(test-path $newfolder)
{ Copy-Item -Path $LBStempfolder -Destination $newfolder
Get-ChildItem -Path $newfolder\* -Include xyz\* -Recurse |
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'xyz', 'abc'} -Force
}}}
Function Get-Outlookfile ($ofile)

{ $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook. Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$email = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($ofile)
$email.HTMLBody = $email.HTMLBody.Replace("XXX-XXX", "myedition")
$email.Subject = $email.Subject("mysubject")
$email.Save()

}
$outlook doc = Get-Outlookfile -ofile $newfolder\\abc.msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` (which does what its name suggests), use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`:

`$email = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($ofile)`

or

`$email = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedItem($ofile)`).

When saving an item, you might also want to use `MailItem.SaveAs(.., olMsgUnicode)` instead of `MailItem.Save`.

Comment: Sorry Dmitry, I couldn't use NameSpace.OpenSharedItem in the script as its not getting recognized within powershell for some reason.

Comment: What is the relevant snippet of your code and what is the exact error?

Comment: I tried like this $email = $outlook.Namespace.OpenSharedItem($ofile) 

email.MailItem.SaveAs($ofile)

Comment: `Namespace` is the name of the object - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace. What you need is either `$email = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($ofile)` or `$email = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedItem($ofile)`

Comment: Okay, I tried that however, script does run but nothing get changed or edit in the file. Not sure where it did the editing.

Comment: What is your latest code that opens, edits,and saves the MSG file? You can add the code to your original question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response Dmitry. I never got to work the "save as .msg file". My last code that work was opens the file in Outlook, did the editing and save it under Draft.

Comment: You said "script does run but nothing get changed or edit in the file". What is your latest code? You can update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Save` method of the `MailItem` class saves the an Outlook item to the current folder in Outlook (not disk) or, if this is a new item, to the Outlook default folder for the item type, in your case it would be the Drafts folder because it has never been saved in Outlook.

If you need to save the created from a template and edited item to the disk, you need to use the [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method which saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path on the disk and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (`.msg`) is used.

So, the code may look like this:

```
$LBStempfolder = Template folder location
$newfolder = new directory location

If(test-path $LBStempfolder)
{ if(!(test-path $newfolder))
{ $newfolder = New-Item -ItemType "Directory" -Path "LBStempfolder" -Name "XYZ" -Confirm
Write-host $newfolder
if(test-path $newfolder)
{ Copy-Item -Path $LBStempfolder -Destination $newfolder
Get-ChildItem -Path $newfolder\* -Include xyz\* -Recurse |
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'xyz', 'abc'} -Force
}}}
Function Get-Outlookfile ($ofile)

{ $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook. Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$email = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($ofile)
$email.HTMLBody = $email.HTMLBody.Replace("XXX-XXX", "myedition")
$email.Subject = $email.Subject("mysubject")
$email.SaveAs($ofile)

}
$outlook doc = Get-Outlookfile -ofile $newfolder\\abc.msg
```

In some case you may be interested in using the [NameSpace.OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.openshareditem) method which opens a shared item from a specified path or URL. See [Import Saved Items using OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/sharing/import-saved-items-using-openshareditem) for more information.

In both cases you need to use the `SaveAs` method save your changes on the disk, so the original item will be overwritten.

But the difference between these two methods is that the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method creates a new item in a composed state, to save it as a received item you need to do extra steps for that, while the `OpenSharedItem` method doesn't change the item state. If that makes sense. Otherwise, both ways are fully valid.

Comment: When I debug using SaveAs option. It gave me error message a null-valued expression. $email.SaveAs(). 
Also, OpenSharedItem was also unsucessful. Seems like PowerShell isn't friendly with Outlook.

Comment: Also, When I ran the script. It did run but .msg file didn't get edited. Neither any entry was saved under draft folder.

Comment: What value do you pass to the [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method?

Comment: I used the same information as in your code. i.e. $email.SaveAs($ofile) and ofile is the path to my file that I want to save it. I was hoping it should have over written the existing file. Although, it didn't do it.

Comment: What is the exact file path?

Comment: $LBSTempfolder = C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Template\xyz.msg
$newfolder = C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\testfolder\abc.msg